# How to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway in Angular 4/5 Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services, ccavenue

I am using an Angular 4/5 application and Asp.net Web Api for my project. How to integrate CCAvenue in my application? Is it possible to redirect from angular 4/5 app to CCAvenue? Or any other method to integrate CCAvenue?